# dynamically added ports can't be cloned in jointjs?

Tags: javascript, port, clone, jointjs

I added ports to an element when click a button.

here is my code

```
joint.shapes.devs.Jointpoint = {}; 
joint.shapes.devs.Jointpoint = joint.shapes.devs.Model
.extend({
    markup : '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><ellipse class="bianyaqiOO" ry="30" rx="30" id="svg_1" cy="30" cx="30" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#222" fill="none"/></g></g>',
    //portMarkup: '<g class="port port<%= id %>"><rect class="port-body"/><text class="port-label"/></g>',
    defaults : joint.util.deepSupplement({
        type : 'devs.Jointpoint',

        ports : {
            groups : {
                'in' : {
                    position : {
                        name : 'top'
                    },
                    attrs : {
                        '.port-label' : {
                            fill : '#000'
                        },
                        '.port-body' : {
                            'fill-opacity' : 0.5,
                            'stroke-opacity' : 0.5,
                            r : 2,
                            magnet : true
                        }
                    },
                    label : {
                        position : {
                            name : 'top',
                            args : {
                                y : -10
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }, joint.shapes.devs.Model.prototype.defaults)
});

joint.shapes.devs.BianyaqiOOView = joint.shapes.devs.ModelView;

var Jointpointicon = new joint.shapes.devs.Jointpoint({
position : {
x : 500,
y : 16
},
size : {
width : 20,
height : 20
},
isInteractive : false,
});
Jointpointicon.addTo(graph);
var selected;
paper.on('cell:pointerup', function (cellView) {
                selected = cellView.model
           if(cellView.model.get('name') == 'addPort'){
                selected.addPort({group:'in');
       });

paper.on('blank:pointerup', function (evt, x, y) {
                graph.addCell(selected.clone());
       });
```

when I clickthe addport button, I can add a port to the selected element,but when I click blank area on the paper, I got selected element cloned,but there is no port,I am not sure what happened , but if I change it like this :

```
var Jointpointicon = new joint.shapes.devs.Jointpoint({
position : {
x : 500,
y : 16
},
size : {
width : 20,
height : 20
},
isInteractive : false,
inPorts : [ 'in' ],
});
```

there will be an 'in' port after loaded, and it can be cloned, but if I add some new ports by click addPort button, all added ports won't be cloned , is there anything I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out what the problem is .
I use addInPort(portname) and addOutPort(portname) instead of addPort(). it worked very well.

seems like the addPort() can not add port to 'in' or 'out', it add port to a new array maybe. so when clone a new cell with added port, it only clone ports in the 'in' and 'out' array, the new added ports were added to a no name array, so it won't be cloned maybe. anyway use addInPort(portname) and addOutPort(portname)  is good way.